# Setting Default Category to Username

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I installed a plugin called "Symbiosis" which creates categories automatically with a user's username upon them signing up.

Whenever any user creates a post on the site, 
I am trying to figure out how to assign that category with the post.

I want to set WP Default Category to the authors username so that when anyone creates a post it automatically posts under their name. (my users do not have access to default wp-panels)

I know about the dropdown in the settings > writing panel but that's not what I'm looking for as I cannot customize the slug to a users name.

Is this possible via plugin or programatically somewhere else?

The categories are all created.
I can pull the loggedin users username and echo it but I'm not sure where to put it:

```
<?php global $current_user; if ( isset($current_user) ) {echo $current_user->user_login;}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this, paste this in your `functions.php`

```
function my_save_post($post_id)
{
    if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    {
        global $current_user;
        if ( isset($current_user) )
        {
            $category_id = get_cat_ID( $current_user->user_login );
            wp_set_post_categories( $post_id, array($category_id) );
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_save_post');
```

Comment: This seems to be creating a new category and renaming that category with the numerical id of the appropriate category. Is there a way just add the post to the category slug (user login)?

Comment: Just use `$category_id = $current_user->user_login;` for username but post needs category ids.

Comment: This works great with your suggestion! - thank you!